# Pass Less.js variable into media query

Tags: css, less

I want to pass this variable into a media query:

```
@browser-main-and-sidebar: @main-width + @main-spacer + @sidebar-width + @outer-padding*2;
```

where:

```
@outer-padding: 20px;
@main-width: 600px;
@main-spacer: 10px;
@sidebar-width: 290px;
```

When I write this out:

```
@media (min-width: @browser-main-and-sidebar) {
    max-width: @browser-main-and-sidebar;
}
```

The CSS generated is:

```
@media (min-width: 600px + 10px + 290px + 20px*2) {
    .Jobzi__core {
        max-width:1240px;
        background: black
    }
}
```

Is there a way to force the compuation of the variable into a single pixel value?

Comment: Put parens around the variable used in `@media`, i.e. `@media (min-width: (@browser-main-and-sidebar)) {...`. Unlike other statements, `@media` always implies [`--strict-math=on`](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-strict-math).

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26912187 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21741531.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [seven-phases-max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29331304/pass-less-js-variable-into-media-query#comment46852268_29331304) stated in the comments above, strict math is implied within `@media` queries.

> [**LESS - Strict Math**](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-strict-math)
>
> With strict math on, only maths that is inside un-necessary parenthesis will be processed.

Therefore you need to wrap the variables that you want to be evaluated within parenthesis:

```
@browser-main-and-sidebar: (@main-width + @main-spacer + @sidebar-width + @outer-padding * 2);
```

..or:

```
@media (min-width: (@browser-main-and-sidebar)) {
    max-width: @browser-main-and-sidebar;
}
```

Both of which will compile to the desired result of:

```
@media (min-width: 940px) {
  max-width: 940px;
}
```

---

```
@outer-padding: 20px;
@main-width: 600px;
@main-spacer: 10px;
@sidebar-width: 290px;
@browser-main-and-sidebar: @main-width + @main-spacer + @sidebar-width + @outer-padding * 2;

@media (min-width: (@browser-main-and-sidebar)) {
    max-width: @browser-main-and-sidebar;
}
```